# Python 3 Zip Password Cracker

Tags: python

I am working on a simple zip file password cracker for a school project, and I need it to display the password once it cracks it from the dictionary word list. Whenever I run it, it only extracts the file, and doesn't print anything. How can I fix this to also show the password? Here is my code.

```
import optparse
import zipfile
from threading import Thread

def extract_zip(zFile, password):
        try:
                password = bytes(password.encode('utf-8'))
                zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
                print ("[+] Password Found: " + password + '\n')
        except:
                pass

def Main():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser("useage &prog "+\
                        "-f <zipfile> -d <dictionary>")

        parser.add_option('-f', dest='zname', type='string',\
                        help='specify zip file')
        parser.add_option('-d', dest='dname', type='string',\
                        help='specify dictionary file')
        (options, arg) = parser.parse_args()
        if (options.zname == None) | (options.dname == None):
                print (parser.usage)
                exit(0)
        else:
                zname = options.zname
                dname = options.dname

        zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zname)
        passFile = open(dname)

        for line in passFile.readlines():
            password = line.strip('\n')
            t = Thread(target=extract_zip, args=(zFile, password))
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] .  You are not asking a question yet so you need to edit your post.

Comment: @DaveS I added the question

Comment: Try printing the exception in the `except:` block.

Comment: What do you mean, @Barmar ? I am sorta new to python

Comment: `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: @Barmar it just floods the cmd prompt instead of giving me a pass

Comment: Simplify your testing, just put the correct password in the password file, so you can see what it's doing when it should print the password.

Comment: @Barmar, ok it seems to work, but it says must be str, not bytes

Comment: that's because you call `bytes(password.encode('utf-8'))`. Why are you converting it to bytes if it doesn't want that?

Comment: @Barmar Now it says expected bytes, got str

Comment: Which function said it expected `str` in the first error?

Comment: Ahh, I get it. You can't use `'string' + bytes` when printing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to print the encoded password instead of the original password. You can't concatenate bytes to a string. So print the original password, not the result of `bytes()`.

And instead of extracting all the files from the archive, use `testzip()` to test whether you can decrypt them. But to do this, each thread needs its own `ZipFile` object. Otherwise they'll set the password used by another thread.

```
def extract_zip(filename, password):
    with ZipFile(filename) as zFile:
        try:
            password_encoded = bytes(password.encode('utf-8'))
            zFile.setpassword(password_encoded)
            zFile.testzip()
            print ("[+] Password Found: " + password + '\n')
        except:
            pass
```

Then change the caller to pass the filename to the thread, not `zFile`.

Comment: also, would there be a way to make it so that it doesn't actually extract the file, and just give the password? And how do I add a feature to print a message saying that no password was found when it can't find one

Comment: @Vixro Note that using a blanket `try`/`except` (i.e., no specific exceptions being caught by the `except`) is a recipe for trouble, because it swallows whatever error is occurring. Presumably there was some exception being thrown when trying to print the encoded bytes that would reveal what the error was, but it wasn't being printed because you caught the exception and then passes.

Comment: @JoshKarpel That's why I told him to add error printing when debugging.

Comment: @Barmar Woops, didn't see the comment thread on the question. My mistake.

Comment: @Vixro Maybe call `setpassword()` and then `testzip()`.

Comment: @Barmar again, sort of a noob. Not sure how to pull that off >.<

Comment: It's in the documentation of the `zipfile` module. `zFile.setpassword(password_encoded)`, `zFile.testzip()`

Comment: @Barmar and how would I go about printing a message when the password wasn't found?

Comment: You can assign a global variable when the password is found. The main function needs to wait for all the threads to finish. If the variable isn't set, then none of them succeeded.

Comment: Please don't ask me to write that for you as well because you're a noob. You need to make an attempt to figure this stuff out. If you're advanced enough to be using threads, you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile
from tqdm import tqdm

def chunck(fd,size=65536):
    while 1:
        x=fd.read(size)
        if not x: 
            break
        yield x

def file_len(path):
    with open(path,'r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as fd:
        return sum(x.count('\n') for x in chunck(fd))

def linear_zip_crack(zip_path,pwd_path):
    ln=file_len(pwd_path)
    zp=zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path)
    with open(pwd_path,'rb') as fd:
        for x in tqdm(fd,total=ln,unit='x'):
            try:
                zp.extractall(pwd=x.strip())
            except:
                continue
            else:
                print(f'pwd={x.decode().strip()}')
                exit(0)
    print('Not found')

linear_zip_crack('spn.zip','pwds.txt')
```

Comment: Instead of just posting a piece of code, you should explain it.